# How do I decide how many partitions to use in Auzre Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Or phrased differently: what reason do I have to not take the max number of partitions (currently 32 without contacting Microsoft directly).

As far as I can tell more partitions means (potential) larger egress throughput, at no added monetary or computational cost. What's the catch? When would I not want to use as many partitions as I am possibly allowed to provision?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in the observation that having a larger number of partitions won't cost you an extra dime when provisioning the event hub. But when the data comes in at scale you will have to allocate more TUs, so it will cost you extra based on the amount of data flowing in and out.

from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-are-event-hubs-throughput-units)

> Throughput in Event Hubs defines the amount of data in mega bytes or the number (in thousands) of 1-KB events that ingress and egress through Event Hubs. This throughput is measured in throughput units (TUs). Purchase TUs before you can start using the Event Hubs service. You can explicitly select Event Hubs TUs either by using portal or Event Hubs Resource Manager templates.

Another thing is that if you are using for example the [Event Processor Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host) to process the data it has to spin up listeners for all partitions. If the incoming data is not that much and the data is divided over all those partitions you will have a lot of partitions dealing with small amount of data flowing in making it possible that there is not an optimal processing of this data.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#how-many-partitions-do-i-need):

> The partition count on an event hub cannot be modified after setup. With that in mind, it is important to think about how many partitions you need before getting started. 
>   Event Hubs is designed to allow a single partition reader per consumer group. In most use cases, the default setting of four partitions is sufficient. If you are looking to scale your event processing, you may want to consider adding additional partitions. There is no specific throughput limit on a partition, however the aggregate throughput in your namespace is limited by the number of throughput units. As you increase the number of throughput units in your namespace, you may want additional partitions to allow concurrent readers to achieve their own maximum throughput.
>
> However, if you have a model in which your application has an affinity to a particular partition, increasing the number of partitions may not be of any benefit to you. For more information, see availability and consistency.

Your data processing pipeline has to deal with those partitions. If you have just one process/machine that has to process the insane amount of data that can theoretically can be send to an event hub.

Comment: But the number of partitions doesn't change the overall ingress or egress volume, just how it is split, surely I would use the same number of TUs regardless of number of partitions? (Except for the fact I'm limited at 1 TU per partition, so they're an upper bound for total throughput, but never a lower bound)

Comment: And regarding single consumer, again, the number of partitions decides just on the upper bound of total consumers, as I can have at most one per partition. But a single consumer can handle any number of partitions. So more partitions equals more scalability, and more flexibility, making me lean towards the max value. Is the only downside the Event Processor Host management overhead?

Comment: From what I've seen, the only time you'd want a single partition is when you would like the events to be processed in order. The events are ordered within each partition. The number of partitions does not affect the ingress but it can affect the egress. Example : If you had Azure functions reading from the event hub, the maximum number of instances the functions can scale to will equal the number of partitions. In short, if you want max egress (within the TU), with no concern of ordering, you'd want max partitions.